# How can i give multiple rules in a decision table excel file for use in drools?

Tags: excel, drools

I have multiple rules in a drl file which i want to convert into a decision table xls file.

**The drl rule file:**

```
package com.src.rules;

global java.util.Map outMap


rule abc

when
$measureFact : MeasureFact( name == "ABC")

then
boolean result1 = $measureFact.ruleId[422] && $measureFact.ruleId[423]  &&  $measureFact.ruleId[372]  &&  $measureFact.ruleId[373];
boolean result2 = result1 && $measureFact.ruleId[272];
boolean result3 = result1 && $measureFact.ruleId[273];

outMap.put(1, result1);
outMap.put(2, result2);
outMap.put(5, result3);


end


rule def

when
$measureFact : MeasureFact( name == "DEF")

then
boolean result1 =$measureFact.ruleId[395] && $measureFact.ruleId[401] &&  $measureFact.ruleId[325] && $measureFact.ruleId[331]
                        && $measureFact.ruleId[22]  && $measureFact.ruleId[332];
boolean result2 = result1 && ($measureFact.ruleId[402] || $measureFact.ruleId[403]);


outMap.put(1, result1 );
outMap.put(2, result2 );

end
```

As of now i can get only one rule working, but that too without giving some value like 'TRUE' or 'FALSE', it won't work. Now, how can i give multiple rules like this in the excel file?

**Decision table excel file:**

[image: The decision table]

Answer (score 0):

It's rather obvious that you cannot do this via a decision table as it is defined and implemented in Drools.

The left hand side isn't the problem, but the right hand side is.

Not knowing what goes on when

```
MeasureFact( name == "GHI" )
```

and so on, I can only suggest that you code the right hand side actions in Java and call the action by right hand side code.

Comment: I found a workaround by swapping the action part with true and changing the true to $param. I will post the answer here.